# IP Blocking and Lighthouse

Tags: ip, pagespeed, lighthouse

I have added the following to .htaccess (using my own IP instead of the???

<FilesMatch ".*">  Require ip ??.?.?.???  /FilesMatch>

I hoped it would be one way of stopping admin access to the Wordpress site. (I am aware that IP spoofing is possible but having had two attacks where the login has been altered, I've got to try something.)
I'm using the Sucuri plugin which tells me about failed attempts and I've upgraded all the relevant passwords.

Now when I try to run Page Speed Insights I get "ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested."

Please keep it simple (I'm not a programmer) but is there a way of whitelisting the Lighthouse IP?